# Drill into CATEGORY CALCULATED MEMBER

Tags: mdx, drilldown, iccube-reporting

with following MDX

```
WITH
  SET [My Countries] as [Customers].[Geography].[Country]
  CATEGORY CALCULATED MEMBER [Customers].[Geography].[Europe].[Benchmark] AS {[Customers].[Geography].[Country].&[FRA], [Customers].[Geography].[Country].&[ITA], [Customers].[Geography].[Country].&[ESP]}
  MEMBER [My Measure] as [Measures].[Amount] ,
          FORMAT_STRING='percent', BACK_COLOR=paletteOutliersLight( 0.5 + 4 * ( currentCellValue() - ([Customers].[Geography].[Europe].[Benchmark],[Amount],[Stats].[Stats-Time].[L-Stats-Time].[Year Change %]) ))
SELECT
[Time].[Year].[Year].[2006]:[Time].[Year].[Year].[2010] ON COLUMNS,
{ [Customers].[Geography].[Europe].[Benchmark]  }
    +
    Order( [My Countries], [Time].[Year].[Year].[2010], BDESC )
    ON ROWS
 FROM [Sales]
    where ([My Measure],[Stats].[Stats-Time].[L-Stats-Time].[Year Change %])
CELL PROPERTIES STYLE, CLASSNAME, VALUE, FORMATTED_VALUE
```

taken as an example from [https://www.iccube.com/livedemo/?ic3reportName=Benchmarking](http://iccube%20Benchmark)

I can get a benchmark composed of different Areas... `[Customers].[Geography].[Europe].[Benchmark]`

But I can't drilldown into those Areas details...   Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: It's for a table or another type of chart ?

Comment: I would say Table & Charts  ;-)    But let's start by a Table if easier...